Simplifying expressions for reinvesting shares at fixed buy and dividend rates - manipulating floor functions
I'm trying to simplify an expression for reinvesting shares at fixed buy and dividend rates.
Assumptions:
$N$ for initial number of shares. $N$ is integer.
2.2p per share is dividend & is fixed.
There are $4$ dividends per year, occurring every 3 months.
Dividends are reinvested the day of receipt.
No charges for reinvesting shares.
Buy price per share is fixed at $109.2$p.
Broker doesn't allow fractional shares to be bought.
Left over money from being unable to buy fractional shares is not reinvested.
First dividend example:
$0.022N$p in value. Dividing $0.022N$p by the buy price of $109.2$p gives $\frac{0.022N}{109.2}$ which is the potential amount purchased by the broker (reinvested dividend), but broker doesn't allow fractional shares so the amount of shares bought is actually the floor of this, so: $\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor$. Then the amount of shares owned after the reinvestment is $N+\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor$.
Second dividend example:
$0.022(N+\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor)$p in value. Dividing this by the buy price of $109.2$p gives $$\frac{0.022(N+\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor)}{109.2}$$ which is the potential amount purchased by the broker (reinvested dividend), but the amount of shares bought is floor of this, so: $$\lfloor\frac{0.022(N+\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor)}{109.2}\rfloor$$ Then the amount of shares owned after the second reinvestment is $$N+\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{0.022(N+\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor)}{109.2}\rfloor$$
Then value of those shares owned using the buy price is $$109.2(N+\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{0.022(N+\lfloor\frac{0.022N}{109.2}\rfloor)}{109.2}\rfloor)p$$
Q1: how can you simplify these two expressions for the shares owed & their value after second dividend reinvested in terms of $N$?
Q2: how can you simplify the formula for the shares owed & their value after $n$ dividends reinvested in terms of $N$?
I have found some inspiration from questions such as Algebraic manipulation of floors and ceilings, however that doesn't explain to me what methods can be used for the simplification.

Let us define $x_n$ to be the number of shares after the $n$'th dividend and then $x_0=N$. Note that $x_n$ is always an integer, so adding it to another number doesn't affect the fractional part of that other number. That means that $x_{n+1}=x_n+\left\lfloor{\frac{0.022 x_n}{109.2}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor x_n +  \frac{0.022 x_n}{109.2}  \right\rfloor =  \left\lfloor \frac{109.222}{109.2} x_n \right\rfloor$.
So let us define $r = \frac{109.222}{109.2}=\frac{54611}{54600}$.
In particular we have after the first dividend $x_1=\lfloor r N\rfloor$ shares and after the second dividend $x_2=\lfloor r \lfloor r N \rfloor \rfloor$.
You cannot make the general expression for $x_n$ much nicer other than rewrite it using modulo operations. You can however give bounds. On the one hand, we see that $x_{n+1}\leq r x_n$, so that $x_n\leq r^n N$. On the other hand, we have at most a fractional part of $\frac{54599}{54600}$, so that  $x_{n+1}\geq r x_n - \frac{54599}{54600}$. Solving this recurrence gives $x_n\geq r^n \left(N - \frac{54599}{11}\right) + \frac{54499}{11}.$ So to conclude we have
$$
r^n \left(N - \frac{54599}{11}\right) + \frac{54599}{11} \leq x_n \leq r^n N.
$$
